# Видит ли запакованный в exe python-скрипт файлы рядом с собой?

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Прикладываю скриншот для наглядности. Сработает ли такая инициализация драйвера?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

Или надо

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="../chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

На себе проверить не могу, т.к. у меня драйвер есть в PATH
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По идее первый вариант. При этом при запуске такого exe файла все его упакованное содержимое распаковывается во временную папку, но текущая директория по идее должна остаться той же самой - той откуда вы файл запустили. Вообще - проще проверить.

Comment: Вроде работает, из venv'а удалил драйвер. Попозже отпишусь сюда наверняка, вдруг кому интересно